# How do I create a candy packet model?

Tags: modeling

[image]
[image]

I downloaded a 3D packet model from blender, but I'm wondering how do I achieve the design where I can put the hole on the top on the packet such as in the second pic? If anyone has a pre-designed model with this design that I can download for free, it would be helpful. Alternatively, if there's a YouTube tutorial available on how to modify a 3D packet model in Blender to include a hole on the top, I would greatly appreciate the guidance.

Comment: You can create the shape of the hole and use the knife project tool to cut off the hole on the pack object?